# Show posts from the users you are following - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have made a following feature where users can follow each other. The problem is that it is not being used the way it should. At the moment when a user is writing a post it will be saved in my Firebase database under this reference:

`FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").childByAutoId()`

The feed-items is where all posts are. I am changing that however now, so when a user is posting something it will be saved here:

`FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child(UserID).child("Posts").childByAutoId()`

I do that because it somehow tells me that would be easier to only show the posts of the people you follow in my apps feed.

At the moment I am getting all the posts for my feed (from feed-items) like this:

```
func startObersvingDB() {
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            var newUpdates = [Sweet]()



            for update in snapshot.children {
                let updateObject = Sweet(snapshot: update as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                newUpdates.append(updateObject)

            }

            self.updates = newUpdates.reverse()
            self.tableView.reloadData()


        }) { (error: NSError) in
            print(error.description)
        }
    }
```

And then I call startObservingDB() in the viewDidLoad.

If you want to see my `Sweet` struct here it is:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import UIKit

struct Sweet {
    let key: String!
    let content: String!
    let addedByUser: String!
    let profilePhoto: String!
    let itemRef: FIRDatabaseReference?


    init (content: String, addedByUser: String, profilePhoto: String!, key: String = "") {
        self.key = key
        self.content = content
        self.addedByUser = addedByUser
        self.profilePhoto = profilePhoto
        self.itemRef = nil

    }

    init (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        key = snapshot.key
        itemRef = snapshot.ref
        path  = key
        if let theFeedContent = snapshot.value!["content"] as? String {
            content = theFeedContent
        } else {
            content = ""
        }

        if let feedUser = snapshot.value!["addedByUser"] as? String {
            addedByUser = feedUser
        } else {
            addedByUser = ""
        }

        if let feedPhoto = snapshot.value!["profilePhoto"] as? String! {
            profilePhoto = feedPhoto
        } else {
            profilePhoto = ""
        }



    }

    func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {
        return ["content":content, "addedByUser":addedByUser, "profilePhoto":profilePhoto!]
    }
}
```

And in my TableViewController I am using this to display name etc. in the custom cell:

```
var update = updates[indexPath.row]

cell.nameLabel.text = update.addedByUser
```

etc. etc.

My question is:
**How do I change that to only show posts from the people I am following?**

Sorry for the long post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are saving your followers list as an dictionary in other parent node like this :-

```
user_followed_by :{
  userID2 : {
      userID1 : true,
      userID5 : true,
      userID6 : true,
      userID12 : true,
      userID99 : true, 
     } 
    }

 users :{
  userID2 :{
      post :{
             postAutoID1 : {...},
             postAutoID2 : {...},
             ...
              }
          }   
    }
  postsToShowToUser :{

     userID1 : {
         postAutoID1 : true,  //These are the post's autoID's of all the users whom
                              // your current user is following
         postAutoID5 : true,
         postAutoID3 : true,
     },


   }

/*    // If you choose to declare a separate section of the post Details in your Database.
  posts_Of_The_User :{

    userID1 : {

       postAutoID1 : {...//DETAILS},
       postAutoID2 : {...//DETAILS},
       postAutoID3 : {...//DETAILS},
      ....
           },

     }  */
```

The idea is that whenever a user whom your current user is following makes a post. That post's ***autoID*** gets appended in the **postsToShowToUser/userID**.

That is, if *userID2* will make a post then a call will be made to append that post's autoID in all users **postsToShowToUser/userID** who are following the *userID2*.

**PS:-** I strongly suggest that you move your post details out of `post` section. Make it a separate parent node consisting of multiple postAutoID's as key and there post data as value. It might come in handy later on, also would avoid nesting data, which would help you navigate through your Database.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand; are you saying that whenever a user is making a post, it should check who is following that user and then add that post to all the users that are following that user? :-) Is it not possible to do this; When a user is posting something it goes in their profile - then all the current users followers gets in an array and checks for posts? I really do not have a clue but adding users posts mulitple places will take some space - right?

Comment: Basically allowing a user to access another users profile is not a good idea. Read what i suggested in PS. Also instead of true in *postsToShowToUser* you can give the userID of  the posting user. Once you have the postID and the userID of the post. Now you can navigate the post details of the postID in the *post* section of the database, w/o giving the access to the user to access other users account.I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: As for appending the postID in every follower, your user could just make a post and then you will have to loop through every users_Follwers and then through their postID from where you will be able to get the postDetails of every recent posts. This is not a bad idea , but you will be giving permission to a random follower to access your other users personal details and also it takes a long time to load all the details and looping through, your app users might not wanna wait that long to read the post's made by their friends...!

Comment: Also you don't have to worry about the network connection being lost while making a post or while your network thread is appending the postID into your followers node. As these calls are made asynchronous and first loaded into local cache, so as your user comes back online those remaining appending ID's will start being appending. :) Happy Coding

Comment: It unfortunately did not :( What I have tried is getting all users that currentUser is following into an array. I am then iterating through that array to get all posts from the users in that array. At first it seems to be working quite well - it is showing the posts it need to but whenever currentUser clicks the like button of a posts created by (lets say...) John Ryan, all posts from John Ryan are duplicated? I have no idea why :(