# Iterate through users to only show their posts in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem. I am trying to iterate through an array of strings, where the users ids that the current user is following is in.

My user is currently following two users and therefore there are two userIDs in the `tableData` array. The problem is with the following code it only shows one of the users posts, not both. It shows the user that I most recently added's post instead of all the users I follow posts. How can I change that?

Hope you understand what I mean. This is my code:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Following").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            var tableData = [String]()

            let title = snapshot.value!["Id"] as? String
            tableData.append(title!)
            print(tableData[0])

            for i in 0..<tableData.count {

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").queryOrderedByChild("profilePhoto").queryEqualToValue(tableData[i]).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            var newUpdates = [Sweet]()



            for update in snapshot.children {
                let updateObject = Sweet(snapshot: update as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                newUpdates.append(updateObject)

            }

            self.updates = newUpdates.reverse()
            self.tableView.reloadData()


        }) { (error: NSError) in
            print(error.description)
        }


            }


            })
```

I also tried this code but now whenever a user clicks like (there is a like button and a comment function too) it is like it is appending all of the same posts again so it duplicates all posts from the user which post I just liked, here is the new code:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Following").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        var newFollowers = [FollowersStruct]()



        for updateFollowers in snapshot.children {
            let updateObjectFollowers = FollowersStruct(snapshot: updateFollowers as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newFollowers.append(updateObjectFollowers)

        }

        self.followings = newFollowers


        print(self.followings.count)




            for i in 0..<self.followings.count {

                let following = self.followings[i]
                print(following)

                FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").queryOrderedByChild("profilePhoto").queryEqualToValue(following.Id).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in




                    for update in snapshot.children {
                        let updateObject = Sweet(snapshot: update as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                        self.newUpdates.append(updateObject)

                    }

                    self.updates = self.newUpdates.reverse()
                    self.tableView.reloadData()


                }) { (error: NSError) in
                    print(error.description)
                }



            }



    }) { (error: NSError) in
        print(error.description)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query to :-

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Following").observeEventType(.Value,...
```

Also if you are making an app that integrates **following**, look at this answer too for DataStructure :  [Data Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40692302/6297658)

Comment: I just added a new test I made - I have also explained the problem with the new code, that apart from the error is doing what I want it to :)

Comment: @FeReTu Avoid extending question from comments, If you have another road block post another question, someone would definitely help also you would wanna give more details in your new question like your Firebase JSON tree, where are you liking the post etc.. . Accept and upvote this as answer if it solved your issue :) Happy coding

Comment: Accept and upvote this as answer if it solved your issue :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

- I have provided a sample solution below. You have to change your query from .childAdded to .Value because, you need to take all the available values. It returns a snapshot with all values under the given reference.
- .Child added is only called when a new data is added and it returns only the newly added data in the snapshot.

  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Following").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
          var tableData = String
          for eachValue in snapshot.children {
            let title = eachValue!["Id"] as? String
            tableData.append(title!)
            print(tableData)
       }

  ```
      for i in 0..<tableData.count {

  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").queryOrderedByChild("profilePhoto").queryEqualToValue(tableData[i]).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
      var newUpdates = [Sweet]()



      for update in snapshot.children {
          let updateObject = Sweet(snapshot: update as! FIRDataSnapshot)
          newUpdates.append(updateObject)

      }

      self.updates = newUpdates.reverse()
      self.tableView.reloadData()


  }) { (error: NSError) in
      print(error.description)
  }


      }


      })
  ```